# Boundary divisor of projective toroidal compactification

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, divisors

If $F$ is a totally real number field with $[F:\mathbb{Q}] = d>1$, $X$ is the moduli space of Hilbert-Blumenthal Abelian varieties for $F$, and $\overline{X}$ is the projective toroidal compactification, then a paper I am reading refers to $D = \overline{X} \setminus X$ as the boundary divisor. But the cusps of $X$ should be points, so $D$ should be a collection of points, which are too high codimension to be called a divisor. So what does this mean?

I have the suspicion that the "projective toroidal compactification" might be something other than what I expect (i.e. not just the union of $X$ with the cusps), so that the boundary will actually be of codimension 1. But it may also be that the boundary divisor refers to the sum of the codimension $1$ pieces, in which case it could just be trivial if all of the irreducible components are of high codimension.

Comment: I think you may thinking about the  Baily-Borel compactification, which adds a finite number cusp in the Hilbert modular case. A toroidal compactification would be a  blow up of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toroidal compactifications of Shimura varieties are smooth, and $D$ will certainly be of codimension one (when it is not empty). There are in fact a number of different compactifications of Shimura varieties to consider each with different desirable properties. For example, there is a smaller minimal compactification which has the property that the sheaf $\omega$ suitably defined extends to an ample bundle, which is nice, but this is usually a singular space, which is bad, but it at least a projective variety, which is good, but the frogurt is cursed, which is bad. If you "complete" your spaces in too brutal a manner it's not clear you even get projective varieties. These compactifications basically only coincide in the simplest cases like the modular curve.

A useful reference to sort this out might be as follows:

https://www.math.ias.edu/~goresky/pdf/compactifications.pdf